# How can I get the size of an std::vector as an int?

Tags: c++, vector, size, constants, unsigned-integer

I tried:

```
#include <vector>

int main () {
    std::vector<int> v;
    int size = v.size;
}
```

but got the error:

```
cannot convert 'std::vector<int>::size' from type 'std::vector<int>::size_type (std::vector<int>::)() const noexcept' {aka 'long unsigned int (std::vector<int>::)() const noexcept'} to type 'int'
```

Casting the expression to `int` like this:

```
#include <vector>

int main () {
    std::vector<int> v;
    int size = (int)v.size;
}
```

also yields an error:

```
error: invalid use of member function 'std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::size_type std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::size() const [with _Tp = int; _Alloc = std::allocator<int>; std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::size_type = long unsigned int]' (did you forget the '()' ?)
```

Last I tried:

```
#include <vector>

int main () {
    std::vector<int> v;
    int size = v.size();
}
```

which gave me:

```
warning: implicit conversion loses integer precision
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: You can use `std::size(v);` it is introduced with c++17

Comment: @anilbey You probably mean `std::ssize(v);` that is introduced with C++20 because `std::size` doesn't fix the last problem.

Comment: @L.F. could you briefly explain the difference between those two?

Comment: @anilbey `std::size` returns an unsigned integer, `std::ssize` returns a signed integer.  Except I just noticed that `ssize` doesn't solve the problem either ...

Answer (score 77):

In the first two cases, you simply forgot to actually call the member function (!, it's not a value) `std::vector<int>::size` like this:

```
#include <vector>

int main () {
    std::vector<int> v;
    auto size = v.size();
}
```

Your third call

```
int size = v.size();
```

triggers a warning, as not every return value of that function (usually a 64 bit unsigned int) can be represented as a 32 bit signed int.

```
int size = static_cast<int>(v.size());
```

would always compile cleanly and also explicitly states that your conversion from `std::vector::size_type` to `int` was intended.

Note that if the size of the `vector` is greater than the biggest number an `int` can represent, `size` will contain an implementation defined (de facto garbage) value.

Answer (score 0):

Easy :) Use the following code instead of your code.

```cpp
auto size = v.size();
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).