# casting a vector's size() as int does not work

Tags: c++, vector

I am learning C++ on the fly and am having problems with vectors so I am writing some programs that use vectors to familiarize myself with them.

I was following the advice from this post regarding printing out the value of a vector's size() call:

[How can I get the size of an std::vector as an int?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31196443/how-can-i-get-the-size-of-an-stdvector-as-an-int)

My code is a simple C++ code:

```
#include <vector>

int main(int argc, char ** argv) {
   /* create an int vector of size 10, initialized to 0 */
   std::vector<int> int_list[10];
   int int_list_size;

   int_list_size = static_cast<int>(int_list.size()); // <-- compilation error here
} // End main()
```

I'm on Ubuntu 16.04 and I get this error:

```
"error: request for member 'size' in 'int_list', which is of non-class type 'std::vector<int> [10]'
```

Since the size of the vector int_list is 10, shouldn't size() return 10, which I can then cast to an int?

Comment: The size of the vectors are each 0.  The size of the array of vectors is 10.  And C-style arrays do not have a `size()` method.

Comment: "I am learning C++ on the fly" - get a good book.

Comment: What do you thing the type of `int_list` is? What does the compiler think it is? (If you are using a IDE, try hovering the cursor over the symbol to get some info about it...)

Comment: You are trying to call `size()` on an *array* of vectors, not on a *particular* vector. A C style array does not have any methods. A C++ style `std::array` does, though

Comment: Neil Butterworth, I'm working through the book "C++ Primer".  It had some examples of <vector> codes and I was working through some of the examples

Comment: I guarantee it didn't have any code like `int_list.size()`

Answer (score 6):

You are not creating a vector, you are creating an array of vector:

```
std::vector<int> int_list[10];
```

You should use:

```
std::vector<int> int_list(10);
```

See:

- https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/vector/
- https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector

Comment: The `, 0` is redundant and cplusplus.com is a rubbish site  (prefer cppreference.com)

Comment: OK, now I see the problem.  I misread "()" as "[]".

Comment: *array of vectors

Comment: @NoDataFound, I found the error.  I misread "()" as "[]".

I'm doing some experimental programming and a related question came up.

If I declare an array of vectors:
    std::vector<int> int_list[10];

this means there's an array and each element in the array is a vector.  

Is there a way to initialize each of the vectors to be of size 5?

    std::vector<int> int_list[10](5) // this doesn't work.

Could I do this without creating a vector of vectors of ints?

Comment: @M.M: Fixed the 0. While you may think that cplusplus is rubbish, cppreference is kind of harder to read (not the content, but how it is styled).

Comment: @SQA777: I don't do enough C++ nowadays to help you with this one. I presume you ought to declare it: `int_list[10] {std::vector(5), std::vector(5), ...}` or use a loop.